# How to solve the PermGen out of memory error?

Tags: android, ant, environment-variables, permgen, dexguard

I am building my android application using ANT build tool.

1. It builds fine when it's running on my local machine with dexgaurd.
2. It runs fine on server when not using dexgaurd.
3. It fails on server when dexgaurd is used.

Server specs:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:          7978       7328        649          0         32        391
-/+ buffers/cache:       6904       1073
Swap:         8188        486       7702
```

Following is the error:

```
[dexguard] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[12:10:04]
[dexguard-package-helper] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/abc/def/custom_rules.xml:60: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[12:10:04]
[ant] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/abc/def/custom_rules.xml:127: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/abc/def/custom_rules.xml:60: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Following is the lines where error occurs:

```
<dexguard
            verbose="${verbose}"
            keystore="${key.store}"
            keystorepassword="${key.store.password}"
            keyalias="${key.alias}"
            keypassword="${key.alias.password}"
            printseeds="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/seeds.txt"
            printusage="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/usage.txt"
            printmapping="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/mapping.txt"
60 - >      configuration="@{configuration}">
            <configuration file="proguard-project.txt" />
            <configuration file="dexguard-project.txt" />
            <configuration file="dexguard-project-${build.target}.txt" />
            <dexguard-options />
            <libraryjar refid="project.target.class.path" />
        </dexguard>

<dexguard-package-helper
      127 ->           configuration="${dexguard.dir}/lib/dexguard-${build.target}.pro">
                    <dexguard-options>
                        <injar path="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"     filter="**.class" />
                        <injar path="${source.absolute.dir}"          filter="!**.java,!.hg**,!**/.hg**,!.git**,!**/.git**,!.svn**,!**/.svn**,!CVS,!CVS/**,!**/CVS,!**/CVS/**,!.cvsignore,!**/.cvsignore,!SCCS,!SCCS/**,!**/SCCS,!**/SCCS/**,!**.orig,!**~,lib/*/*.so,!**.so,!**.keep,!**.DS_Store,!**.aidl,!**.rs,!**.rsh,!**.d,!**.java,!**.scala,!**.scc,!**.swp,!**.bak,!**thumbs.db,!**picasa.ini,!**package.html,!**overview.html,!**.AIDL,!**.RS,!**.RSH,!**.D,!**.JAVA,!**.SCALA,!**.SCC,!**.SWP,!**.BAK,!**THUMBS.DB,!**PICASA.INI,!**PACKAGE.HTML,!**OVERVIEW.HTML" />
                        <injar refid="project.all.jars.path"          filter="!org/w3c/dom/**,!org/xml/sax/**,!org/xmlpull/v1/**,!org/json/JSON*,!org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class,org/apache/http/Consts.class,org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.class,org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.class,org/apache/http/util/Args.class,org/apache/http/util/Asserts.class,org/apache/http/util/CharsetUtils.class,org/apache/http/util/NetUtils.class,org/apache/http/util/TextUtils.class,!org/apache/http/*,!org/apache/http/auth/*,!org/apache/http/auth/params/*,!org/apache/http/client/*,!org/apache/http/client/entity/*,!org/apache/http/client/methods/*,!org/apache/http/client/params/*,!org/apache/http/client/protocol/*,!org/apache/http/client/utils/*Utils.class,!org/apache/http/conn/*,!org/apache/http/conn/params/*,!org/apache/http/conn/routing/*,!org/apache/http/conn/scheme/*,!org/apache/http/conn/ssl/*,!org/apache/http/conn/util/*,!org/apache/http/cookie/*,!org/apache/http/cookie/params/*,!org/apache/http/entity/*,!org/apache/http/impl/*,!org/apache/http/impl/auth/*,!org/apache/http/impl/client/*,!org/apache/http/impl/conn/*,!org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/*,!org/apache/http/impl/cookie/*,!org/apache/http/impl/entity/*,!org/apache/http/impl/io/*,!org/apache/http/io/*,!org/apache/http/message/*,!org/apache/http/params/*,!org/apache/http/protocol/*,!org/apache/http/util/*,META-INF/services/**,!META-INF/**,!.hg**,!**/.hg**,!.git**,!**/.git**,!.svn**,!**/.svn**,!CVS,!CVS/**,!**/CVS,!**/CVS/**,!.cvsignore,!**/.cvsignore,!SCCS,!SCCS/**,!**/SCCS,!**/SCCS/**,!**.orig,!**~,**.class,lib/*/*.so,!**.so,!**.keep,!**.DS_Store,!**.aidl,!**.rs,!**.rsh,!**.d,!**.java,!**.scala,!**.scc,!**.swp,!**.bak,!**thumbs.db,!**picasa.ini,!**package.html,!**overview.html,!**.AIDL,!**.RS,!**.RSH,!**.D,!**.JAVA,!**.SCALA,!**.SCC,!**.SWP,!**.BAK,!**THUMBS.DB,!**PICASA.INI,!**PACKAGE.HTML,!**OVERVIEW.HTML" />
                        <injar path="${out.native.libs.absolute.dir}" filter="lib/*/*.so" />
                        <injar path="${out.absolute.dir}/${resource.package.file.name}" />
                        <outjar path="${out.final.file}" />
                    </dexguard-options>
                </dexguard-package-helper>
```

Following is the environment variable and its value: ANT_OPTS

```
[echo] ant build config -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

I have changed the  of XX:MaxPermSize to 4096 but it still gives the same error. It consistently fails at this point no mater what the -Xms -Xmx -XX values are. Do I have to add some other value to environment so that it starts working fine. The general solution in these kind of problems is increasing the memory value in -XX:MaxPermSize but it's not helping

More Context: The ant builds 8 applications. The build works fine till the 6th application and all of them have similar custom_rules.xml file. But it fails when it is building 7th application.

If you need more information then mention it in the comment section I'll add it. I have googled a lot regarding this problem and tried to solve it using the solutions, but was never successful.